# How to remove a parenthesized part at the end of a string?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have stock list values like this

```
VALANTINE (BY ECK) DAMIER STONE(XL)
SARIYER (BY ECK) MNV1983(XL7)
```

I want to update stocks list values to this

```
VALANTINE (BY ECK) DAMIER STONE
SARIYER (BY ECK) MNV1983
```

How can I remove the parenthesized part at the end of the string?

Comment: Which version of Firebird are you using?

Comment: My firebird version is 2.5

Comment: Is this second parenthesised value always at the end, or can it also occur in the middle?

Comment: Second paranthesis always at the end

Comment: Are there also cases where there is only a couple of parentheses at the end, and not in the middle (e.g. "SOMETHING SOMETHING(XL)"), and if so, do you want them removed?

Comment: Yes parantheses romeved with inside data

Comment: Ok, so your actual requirement is to remove parentheses at the end?

Comment: Yes i want to remove

Answer (score 0):

In Firebird 2.5, you can do something like:

```sql
case when val similar to ('%\(%\)') escape '\'
  then substring(val from 1 for char_length(val) - position('(' in reverse(val)))
  else val
end
```

This does the following:

- Check with [`similar to`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predsiimilarto) if the string ends with a parenthesized part, if not, it returns the value as is.
- If it does, it will use [`substring`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring) to return the part without the last parenthesized part.

  - It uses [`char_length`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-char-length) to get the original string length,
  - It uses [`reverse`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-reverse) to reverse the string (e.g. `A (B) C (D)` becomes `)D( C )B( A`,
  - It uses [`position`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-position) to find the opening parenthesis (`(`) in the reversed string (this is the last opening parentheses in the original string),
  - It then uses that position to calculate the length for the substring result.

In Firebird 3.0 and later you can also use the regular expression [`substring`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-substring) variant:

```sql
coalesce(substring(val similar '\"%\"\(%\)' escape '\'), val)
```

This does the following:

- With the regular expression substring, extract the part before the final parenthesized part
- As the previous step returns `null` if there is no parenthesized part, it uses [`coalesce`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-coalesce) to return the original value for that case

See this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=9499aa7c90634fc4f5957879c512155c